# Do not change the path with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, python-telegram-bot

Ι need to change the paths using `subprocess` but it doesn't work

I am using `py3.6 - python-telegrambot`

it's my code

```
def sh(bot,update):
  ID = 289444284
  command=update.message.text
  print(command)
  su = subprocess.getstatusoutput(command)
  bot.sendMessage(ID,su[1] )
```

and also

```
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()
subprocess.getoutput(command)
os.system(command)
```

But when I put the cd command back, I'm on the same path and the path does not change

![enter image description here][1]

[1]: [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXtat.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call any of the above (`subprocess.*` or `os.system()`) you create a new (child) process if you run `cd` this way, you change current working directory only for the `cd` itself, but it does not affect your running python code and any command you execute afterwords. You'd need to use `os.chdir()` or just hold that information and pass it into newly created children processing with `cwd` keyword of `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer well-asked questions", and the bullet within regarding questions which "*have already been asked and answered many times before*".